# Phonegap +Framework7 Not Working Android 4.2

Tags: android, cordova, html-framework-7

I have created a app template using framework7 and using phonegap for apk build. App is not rendering the css in my phone which is android 4.2. It is working perfectly in upper version of android. Please help me to fix the issue

Comment: what do you mean by "css is not rederred ?" did you try with android studio emulator ?

Comment: I came into this problem before, and if you are sure it's not a native problem from your apk then you have to remove `minimum-scale=1` from the `viewport` meta tag, that was a long story with 4.2 and before for me. Anyway, it would be better if you can share your project URL so that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

It's because F7 css are based on flexbox and there are issues on older android browser.
You can use Crosswalk in your application to use chrome as webview to fix this issue.